# How to i update this jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I am using this [plugin](http://pastie.org/3837017) and I want to update the timer.

I can start the countdown timer at 5000 milliseconds left like this:

```
$('#CountdownTimer').countdown({ remaining : 5000});
```

But when I try to update it with this call, I guess I initialize it again or something because the timer doesn't update like I assumed

```
$('#CountdownTimer').countdown('update', 2000);
```

It basically speeds up the countdown timer and if I run this again, it speeds it even more... But what I want to do is reset it to 2000 milliseconds

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't used this function before, but it looks like this should work:

```
$('#CountdownTimer').countdown('destroy');
```

Just call it before reinitializing the countdown.

**EDIT**

In the library, change the line:

```
tick_interval = setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

to read

```
if (tick_interval == null) tick_interval = setInterval(tick, 1000);
```

Comment: Oops, I was looking at the wrong countdown library.  Try my other idea.

Comment: does that change the fact that it goes faster after i call the update

Comment: This should fix the problem where it was going faster after the update call.  The problem is you ended up with two (or more) timers decrementing the counter.

Comment: I think you should reset using the syntax of the initial call $('#CountdownTimer').countdown({ remaining : 1234});

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10376/discussion-between-matt-and-pilotcam)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading the library code correctly, 'update()' only updates the *displayed* time remaining, not the actual countdown clock. There doesn't seem to be a way to do what you want as it's written right now, but it wouldn't be to hard to add that functionality if you wanted to do it yourself...

Comment: i have tried to add a function....can you give an example because everything i try reinitializes the timer and it makes it go twice as fast

Comment: `var updateTimeRemaining = function (new_time_remaining){
        seconds_remaining = new_time_remaining;
        update(seconds_remaining);
};`

Comment: yes but everytime i call that or any other funtion it recalls the initialize and makes the countdown speed up

Comment: any way to aviod that from happening

Comment: Actually, now that I look at it more, this library isn't set up to do anything except spin off a countdown timer and let it run until it terminates. All the methods are defined in such a way as to make them all private. When you call "$('#CountdownTimer').countdown('update', 2000);" you're initializing a new counter (but with the same countdown clock, which is why you start getting two ticks per second) on the non-existant element '#update' and the second parameter is just being ignored. You could rewrite it to support public method calls, or you could find a better library (my recommendation)